# My Javascript not pushing my @RendorBody down

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a website and my JavaScript is not being picked up by my `@RenderBody()` `div`s.

Here is my HTML with bootstrap code for the **masterlayout**.

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>

</head>
<body  onresize="onResize()">
    <div id="masterlayout" class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li></li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    @if (1 == 1)
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Site Admin", "RegisterUsers", "SiteAdmin")</li>
                    }
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Promotional", "Promotional", "Promotional")</li>
                    <li class="nav-item nav-link mx-1">@Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div >           
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")            
        </nav>
        <div style="background-color: darkgray; width: 100%; height: 10px;">


        </div>

    </div>
    
    <div id="content1" class="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the code for my **child page**.

```html
<body>
    <div class="sidenav">
        <div id="menu" class="navbar-text">
            @if (1 == 1)
            {
                @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                .Name("Menu")
                .Direction(MenuDirection.Left)
                .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
                .Scrollable(true)
                .Items(items =>
                    {
                       items.Add().Text("Register Employees").Action("RegisterUsers", "SiteAdmin").Visible(Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Administrators"));
                       items.Add().Text("Edit Roles").Action("ManageRoles", "SiteAdmin");
                    })
    )
            }
        </div>
    </div>    
        <div id="content1">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is the **JavaScript**.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content1").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    });

    function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content1").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
    function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Here is my **CSS**.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    min-width: 500px;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 220px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
    /*font-size: 28px;  Increased text to enable scrolling */
    padding:  14px;
}
```

When I resize the browser window to make it smaller, the navbar and menu bar both resize and push down. The `@RenderBody()` doesn't. You can see in the 2 pictures, the first being normal and 2nd being minimized that the menu dropped down automatically on resize. The @RenderBody didn't.

[image: NormalSize]

[image: minimized]

How do I initialize the JavaScript where it moves my `@RenderBody` like it does with my menu?

Comment: Java and javascript have nothing to do with each other. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: javascript is not a java scripting langage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a rookie mistake. The reason it didn't work is I didn't call my 2nd function, nor did I name the 2nd function something else.

**Body and Tags**

`<body  onresize="onResize()">`

`<div id="content1" class="main">@RenderBody()</div>`

`<div id="menu" class="navbar-text">`

**Functions**

```
function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content1").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
```

As you can see, I did not add a 2nd function to be called by the body, nor did I give a different function name. I named them both onResize, and thought it would call both with 1.

This is the correct way.

**Body and Tags**

`<body  onresize="onResize(),onResize2()">`

`<div id="content" class="main">@RenderBody()</div>`

`<div id="menu" class="navbar-text">`

**Functions**

```
    function onResize() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("menu").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
    function onResize2() {
        var height = document.getElementById("masterlayout").offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById("content").style.marginTop = height - 1 + 'px';
    }
```

Rookie mistake, but this is what happens when you take over a project from someone else.